# Dropbox add to Computer Menu in Nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, dropbox

I was wondering if there was any way to "bookmark" dropbox in nautilus on the left hand side? Would be useful to have. I tried searching but had no success, so I apologise in advanced if this has already been ask.

Thanks in advanced for all responses! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to your dropbox folder, click the `Bookmarks` menu item and select `Add bookmark`:

[image]

Or you can simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Thank's I'm highlighting the folder and pressing both CTRL + D as well as selecting it from the menu but nothing happens..?

Comment: You need to double click the folder first, you need to be **inside** the folder you want to bookmark. Just highlighting it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you like command line, you could edit ~/.gtk-bookmarks

Syntax:

```
protocol://Location Name

like

file:///home/user/folder My Bookmark

or

ftp://servername/folder My FTP Location
```

as you can see, anything after the first space is the name you'll see in nautilus